# How to access concatenated columns in Record using FOR Cursor Loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Trying to use records with the cursor and later index by table in the mix.

```
DECLARE CURSOR emp_cur IS
    SELECT employee_id, first_name||' '|| last_name "name"
    FROM employees 
    ORDER BY salary desc;

emp_rec emp_cur%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN 
    FOR emp_rec IN emp_cur
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee ID:'||emp_rec.employee_id||CHR(10)||
                             'Employee Name:'||emp_rec.name);
        EXIT WHEN emp_cur%ROWCOUNT = 10;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

When I run above code I get

```
 ERROR at line 13, "NAME" must be declared.
```

How can I access the column first_name||' '||last_name inside the For loop? or do I just have to do traditional OPEN, simple loop, FETCH and close?

Comment: I believe I don't have to declare emp_rec in DECLARE section as FOR loop automatically does that but question remains the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close; the problem is just that identifiers that are *not* in double-quotes get converted to uppercase, while identifiers that *are* in double-quotes do *not*. So `name`, `NAME`, and `"NAME"` are equivalent to each other, and all of them are different from `"name"`. Either change this:

```
first_name||' '|| last_name "name"
```

to this:

```
first_name||' '|| last_name name
```

or else, if you prefer, change this:

```
'Employee Name:'||emp_rec.name
```

to this:

```
'Employee Name:'||emp_rec."name"
```